# how to solve the table index is nil problem?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

```
`git clone https://github.com/LazyVim/starter ~/.config/nvim

Error detected while processing /home/lx/.config/nvim/init.lua:
Invalid plugin spec {
checker = {
enabled = true
},
defaults = {
lazy = false,
version = false
},
install = {
colorscheme = { "tokyonight", "habamax" }
},
performance = {
rtp = {
disabled_plugins = { "gzip", "tarPlugin", "tohtml", "tutor", "zipPlugin" }
}
},
spec = { { "LazyVim/LazyVim",
import = "lazyvim.plugins"
}, {
import = "plugins"
} }
}
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/core/plugin.lua:80: table index is nil

stack traceback:
...local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/core/plugin.lua:80: in function 'add'
...local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/core/plugin.lua:116: in function 'normalize'
...local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/core/plugin.lua:217: in function 'spec'
...local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/core/plugin.lua:225: in function 'load'
/home/lx/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/init.lua:45: in function 'setup'
/home/lx/.config/nvim/lua/config/lazy.lua:9: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
/home/lx/.config/nvim/init.lua:2: in main chunk
`
```

I use lazyvim as the package manager, using the official example,initialization times got some errors.I did some experimenting and found that I could only load other plugins using setup("plugins")

why is there something wrong with setup({spec = {{import = "plugins"}}})

Answer (score 0):

the gcc version is too high, install gcc9